# How to capture voice PCM data over a serial port and process?

Tags: linux, serial-port, voice, modem, pcm

I have a telephony modem (SIM5320EVB) which gives voice data on ttyUSB0 as PCM with 1600 bytes each 100ms.Iam able to see the data on minicom. How to capture the PCM data in linux (i use ubuntu)and hear it live on the fly or atleast save and play the data? Is there any application available or API? If the approach atleast is suggested I will try developing one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > my_cap_file
# make some noise for 5s for example, then hit ^C
```

then get [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/?lang=ru) and try to open your file with it, trying different input formats. You should be able to hear the sound you produced if you will guess the right format.

Comment: That worked great.Thanks. it was signed 16bit PCM at 8000hz. how do make this realtime, ie. how to play the data raw as and when it comes through the tty.My intention is to route this modem audio data to the interfaced main application board's audio interface.

Comment: smth like `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > /dev/pcm0`. I don't know how to set pcm0 to 8KHz

Comment: do i need to create a pcm device for this purpose. ? or my little knowledge says to write a driver which reads up serial data and creates a pcm devices to upper layer from kernel. is this approch a valid one. I tried googling to create a pcm device.but could not succeed as i lack in terminologies used.

Comment: `/dev/pcmX` are created by kernel driver for your souncard AFAIK

Comment: You could also use svox or aplay with the right options.

Answer (score 0):

Install `sox` for the `play` command and use: `play -r 8000 -c 1 -t raw -e signed-integer -b 16 /dev/ttyUSB0`. That is: bit rate 8KHz, 1 channel (mono), raw data (PCM), format is signed integer 16 bits wide, and data can be read from ttyUSB0.

That requires `sox` to be able to play audio on your system; I've had success with `pulseaudio` for the underlying sound system.

You may need to modify the buffer size for `play`. By default, it buffers data which creates a small but very noticeable delay.